# Unity.FromJason invalid Values while Parsing

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

When trying to desearialize data from a Json i get an invalid Values Error.
For experimenting i cut down the number of keys/values.
I did my best to find a solution but i never worked with json.

```
  {"id": 2} //all code inside my json

public class Weapon
{public int id;}

Debug.Log(JsonUtility.FromJson<Weapon>("/Resources/db/wargear.json"));


ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid value.
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you're trying to parse is the literal path `"/Resources/db/wargear.json"`.

You must first load the JSON file as a text asset and pass the text inside to the JSON deserializer function.

```
public class Weapon
{
    public int id;
}

void Start()
{
    var textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("db/wargear.json");
    var weapon = JsonUtility.FromJson<Weapon>(textAsset.text);
    Debug.Log(weapon.id);
}
```

Comment: Well there are other (better) ways of loading a file but yes ;) In general **[Don't use `Resources`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) at all!** ;)